# Using ocamlc to compile libraries independently

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I have three files:

```
$ ls
lib.ml  desk.ml  test.ml

$ cat lib.ml
let myfunction () = print_endline "Hello world"

$ cat desk.ml
module Liberty = Lib

$ cat test.ml
Desk.Liberty.myfunction ()
```

I want to compile a `desk.cma` that does **not** expose the module `Lib`, but is able to make use of it. For example, I've tried:

```
$ ocamlc -a lib.ml -o lib.cma
$ ocamlc -a lib.cma desk.ml -o desk.cma
$ ocamlc desk.cma test.ml -o test.byte
```

Unfortunately, if you change `test.ml` to be `Lib.myfunction ()`, the same compilation steps work just fine. I want it so that `Lib` is not exposed to `test.ml` and only exposed to `desk.ml`. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for the `-pack` mechanism of OCaml. This allows you to create a `pack.cmo` (or `pack.cmx` for native compilation) from several compilation units, like a `pack.cma` library, but with the added advantage that you can have a corresponding `pack.mli` interface with which you can hide the parts that should be internal to your `pack`. In your example, you could for instance have:

-- lib.ml --

```
let myfunction () = print_endline "Hello world"
```

-- liberty.ml --

```
include Lib
```

-- desk.mli --

```
(* No module Lib: Lib will not be seen outside of the pack. *)

module Liberty: sig
  val myfunction: unit -> unit
end
```

Then you can compile that with

```bash
ocamlc -for-pack Desk -c lib.ml
ocamlc -for-pack Desk -c liberty.ml
ocamlc desk.mli
ocamlc -pack -o desk.cmo lib.cmo liberty.cmo
```

This will give you a module `Desk`, that contains only `Liberty` a sub-module. Of course, `desk.mli` can be used to get more fine-grained restriction, e.g. with

```
module Lib: sig end

module Liberty: sig val myfunction: unit -> unit end
```

you export `Lib` with an empty signature, thus hiding a single (albeit the only one in the example ;-P) function from `Lib`.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking that `Lib` be a module of `desk.cma` that `Desk` can use, but no other modules. I'm pretty sure the structure of a cma file doesn't offer this kind of control.

If you define `Lib` inside `Desk` you can make it a hidden detail.

```
$ ls
desk.ml  desk.mli test1.ml test2.ml test3.ml

$ cat desk.ml
module Lib = struct
    let myfunction () = print_endline "Hello world"
end
module Liberty = Lib

$ cat desk.mli
module Liberty : sig
val myfunction : unit -> unit
end

$ cat test1.ml
Desk.Liberty.myfunction ()

$ cat test2.ml
Lib.myfunction ()

$ cat test3.ml
Desk.Lib.myfunction ()
```

The Liberty module is visible to the test programs, but the Lib module isn't:

```
$ ocamlc -c desk.mli
$ ocamlc -a desk.ml -o desk.cma
$ ocamlc desk.cma test1.ml -o test1.byte
$ ./test1.byte
Hello world
$ ocamlc desk.cma test2.ml -o test2.byte
File "test2.ml", line 1, characters 0-14:
Error: Unbound module Lib
$ ocamlc desk.cma test3.ml -o test3.byte
File "test3.ml", line 1, characters 0-19:
Error: Unbound module Desk.Lib
```

You can implement Lib in a separate file, then `include` it into the definition of the `Desk.Lib` module.

I suspect this isn't a fully satisfying answer, but I hope it's helpful.